# How do I install sqlite3 on windows with the .dll?

Tags: dll, download

On SQLite's official page, you can find the downloads.
https://www.sqlite.org/download.html.
Under the `Precompiled Binaries for Windows` header, I installed the `64-bit DLL (x64)`. I have the dll file now in a zip, but I haven't worked much with windows as I mainly work on a mac. What am I supposed to do with this dll file?

Comment: What do you want to do with sqlite3?

Comment: @ssbssa I want to use it in my terminal like I do on a mac. I want to be able to use a command like "sqlite3 data.db" and be able to edit and read from it with sql commands.

Comment: Then you downloaded the wrong zip file, you need the command-line tools, not the dll.

Comment: Ah ok thanks @ssbssa